omitting articles in checklists
https://www.osha.gov/etools/computer-workstations/checklists/evaluation
When I search for checklists for machinery or equipment, I sometimes see sentences which do not have articles at the beginning. Like the sentences in the attached link, they did not put articles before "Chair has" or "Seat is". Why do they omit articles?

SEATING - Consider these points when evaluating the chair.



Backrest has height adjustability so support is provided for the lower back (lumbar area).
Chair has a sturdy 5 leg base.
Seat is cushioned and rounded with a "waterfall" front (no sharp edge).



Brevity.
When the text is not connected text (eg a headline, a sign, the caption for a picture, or a checklist) it does not need to be complete sentences to make its meaning clear, and small words are often left out - particularly articles and "is/was/were". See Headlinese in Wikipedia.

Also partly just convention. For some reason it's common to write instruction manuals and so forth in a sort of headlinese-ish style: "Fold Tab A and insert into slot B."

I got it! Thank you very much!

Compare also the older notion of telegram style.

The sentences in the example given are complete sentences, only articles are left out. They are  zero article sentences and not headlines.

OP's query is on the omission of the article:

Like the sentences in the attached link, they did not put articles before "Chair has" or "Seat is".
Why do they omit articles?

This is an example of "zero article" usage. Zero article refers to the absence of articles  (the, a, an) before nouns.
There are a number of rules where we don't use any article and it is given in the shared link.
The checklist is from Occupational Safety and Health (OSHA).

"This checklist can help you create a safe and comfortable computer workstation.".

Backrest has height adjustability so support is provided for the lower back (lumbar area).
Chair has a sturdy 5 leg base.
Seat width and depth should accommodate the specific user (seat pan should be wide enough for ease of egress and deep enough to support the entire thigh but not so deep that user cannot utilize lumbar support.)


The checklist by OSHA follows the guidelines since it is a technical instruction related to improving the "Ergonomics" (relating to the design of furniture or equipment which makes it comfortable and effective for people who use it.).

Reference englishclub.com.
One of the rules for Zero article states that
ZERO Article::
Newspaper Headlines, Notices, User Guides, instructions,
https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-zero-article.php

Zero article helps to focus on essential information and creates a concise, objective tone.

I disagree with the last paragraph, which I think is a set of mistaken rationalisations. It's nothing to do with whether the nouns are "generic" or not; if "Zero article helps to focus on essential information", why don't we use it for spoken instructions; and as to the last point, it is indeed concise, but I don't see why it is any more objective.

@ColinFine Your answer says that the given examples are headlines. They are instructions. As a rule, zero articles are used for technical instructions..  why don't we use it for spoken instructions;. It's a rule of grammar. Instructions are complete sentences. - "Chair has a sturdy 5 leg base"

"Chair has a sturdy 5 leg base" is not an instruction. Instructions are often in the imperative: "Before applying [the cream], wash [the] skin  with a mild detergent"

Colin Fine's answer does not say the OP's sentences are examples of headlinese, he is saying they belong to the category of not connected text the link illustrates how newspaper headlines omit "small words" e.g. conjunctions: and, articles, is/are/was/were  etc. From the website ThoughtCo: “… textlinguistics, […] texts are classified into text types, or genres, such as road signs, news reports, poems, conversations, etc.”

@Mari-LouA The sentences are Evaluation Guidelines and only article are missing or are not used making them "zero article sentences". I didn't find anything else missing in the sentences.

You defined "chair has a sturdy 5 leg base" and others  as instructions, in your reply to Colin Fine. They aren't. The term "evaluation guidelines" seems reasonable enough. But CF is not calling the OP's  sentences headlinese, he's saying that omitting articles is a way  of shortening  sentences/phrases/information/ instructions. The checklist is shorter without sacrificing comprehensability.

@Mari-LouA I noticed the wiki link in Colin Fine's answer is to  "headlines".  It is totally wrong way of explaining zero article . "it does not need to be complete sentences to make its meaning clear, and small words are often left out" All the sentences are complete sentences and they can be called either instructions or guidelines.  Guidelines and instructions are synonyms. Dictionary meaning guideline = information intended to advise people on how something should be done or what something should be: instruction noun = (ORDER) something that someone tells you to do:

Evaluation guidelines, a guideline can be used to evaluate whether something complies to a certain criteria. A way to shorten a sentence is not the same thing as saying these are not sentences. Where did I say they are incomplete sentences? The original post, before the edit, had fragments, I added the cited examples in their full form.  So, I am done, forever, with commenting on anything you post in the future. And I'm guessing you'll be fine with that also.

@Mari-LouA The main points to be discussed and remained unanswered are 1. Are the sentences incomplete sentences? 2. Are the sentences examples of zero article or ellipses? 3. Is there anything  missing in the sentences other than articles ?
Instead the discussion has drifted to whether the sentence is instruction or  guidelines. If you search for synonyms of "guidelines", you will find "instructions"

In a technical context such as the OSHA (Occupational Safety and Health Administraton) manual, they leave them out because they aren't needed for the sentence to make sense. Putting in all the 'the's would not improve readability.
WORK STATIONS - Arrange and adjust the computer workstation to promote neutral postures.

Head and neck are balanced and in-line with torso (ears directly above the shoulders not bent forward or back). If "no" refer to Monitors, Chairs and Work Surfaces.
Head, neck, and trunk facing forward (not twisted to view monitor/work/documents). If "no" refer to Monitors or Chairs.

The lack of articles is explicitly used in their defintions of terms. That's all.
[This is not headlinese at all]

So should I only put articles where I think it would improve readability? e.g. the lower, inside the?

@JiroF. No, as you can see by the OSHA examples, it works for defintions of terms. :)

Ok. So regarding the examples given in my question, only articles omitted are the or a before Backseat, Chair, and Seat because they are the terms?

Yes, the sentences describe those parts. BUT notice: ears directly above the shoulders. So, it's only the initial description of the term that has no "the".

Ok! I think I got it. Thank you very much.
